# jQuery.validate: no handlers being fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following javascript running on my page:

```
$("form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            console.log(errors);
        }
        validator.focusInvalid();
    },
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        console.dir(errorList);
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log(form);
    }
});
$("form").valid();
```

I'm invoking this javascript inside my own function rather than binding it directly to any *submit* event.

My problem is that none of those handlers inside the options object being passed to `.validate()` will run; none of the console messages are ever logged.

The validation *does work*, the invalid fields are embellished with a CSS class.

So if the validation is running, why are those events not running?

**EDIT:**

To say the <form> element is long would be an understatement. However, while building/testing, only three <input> elements have the `required` attribute. Furthermore, because I'm posting back asynchronously rather than submitting, the <form> element does not have a populated `action` attribute.

```
<form action="" name="order" id="order" class="margin-b-50">

    <label for="frm-order-name">Order Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="frm-order-name" name="frm-order-name" class="form-control" required="required" data-val-required="You must enter an order name" />

    <label for="frm-username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="frm-username" name="frm-username" class="form-control" required="required" data-val-required="You must enter your username" />

    <label for="frm-password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="frm-password" name="frm-password" class="form-control" required="required" data-val-required="You must enter your password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"My problem is that none of those handlers inside the options object being passed to `.validate()` will run; none of the console messages are ever logged.  The validation does work, the invalid fields are embellished with a CSS class.  So if the validation is running, why are those events not running?"*

I don't think that's possible.  If the validation is working, then those callback functions *must* be firing.

Does your browser support `console.log` and `console.dir`?

This variation is working fine for me...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#order').validate({
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            alert('invalidHandler fired - no of errors: ' + errors);
            console.log('invalidHandler fired - no of errors: ' + errors);
            validator.focusInvalid();
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            console.log('showErrors fired');
            console.dir(errorList);
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            alert('submitHandler fired - form is valid');
            console.log('submitHandler fired - form is valid');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#order').valid();

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/B5N6q/**

And this is your version, also working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/B5N6q/1/